# Read json file and display the values in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to read a json file and display the values in a table. I've tried

```
this.http.get('./data/file.json')
   .map(response => response.json())
   .subscribe(result => this.results =result,
    function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)}, 
    function() { console.log(this.results)});
```

and this:

```
this.http.get("./data/file.json")
  .map(response => { return <ITest[]>(<ITest[]>response.json())})
  .subscribe(result => this.results =result,
    function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)}, 
    function() { console.log(this.results)});
```

but I'm always getting `undefined` in the console. The `GET` response is ok, I can see the response in the network view in debugger. I don't know what I'm missing.

The html looks like:

```html
 <ng-container  *ngFor='let stat of results;let i = index' [attr.data-index]="i">
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left!important;" class="table-row">{{stat.Name}}</td>
      <td class="table-row"> </td>
      <td class="table-row">{{stat.Age}} </td>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let subitem of stat.Intervals">
      <td style="text-align:right!important;">{{subitem.StartDate}}</td>
      <td>{{subitem.EndDate}}</td>
      <td >{{subitem.Duration}}</td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: how **does** your response look like?

Answer (score 2):

Use arrow operator `=>` instead of `function()`. If you are using `function()` you will loose the scope of `this` and hence get undefined.

```
    this.http.get('./data/file.json')
                      .map(response => response.json())
                      .subscribe(result => this.results =result,
                         error=> console.log(error),
                         () => console.log(this.results));
```

Comment: In this way I'm getting the values in the console, which is ok, but my table is not populated with the values....

Comment: Any errors on browser's console? And can you show how `this.results` look like?

Comment: no errors in console...(16) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] -> this is the result, after expanding one of the objects I`m getting this: Object
Name
:
"Tito"
Age
:
"20"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: can you post your json please?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `async` in template, since you are manually subscribing. If you were not to use `subscribe` **then** use `async`, because it does the subscription for you.

Also, use fat arrow syntax for keeping the context of `this`., just like Amit said. So change that code to what Amit has presented:

```
this.http.get('./data/file.json')
   .map(response => response.json())
   .subscribe(result => this.results =result,
     error=> console.log(error),
     () => console.log(this.results));
```

As for why nothing is displayed in template is because you are using wrong property names. This is case sensitive, so response you are receiving has properties `Name` and `Age` based on your comment. So what you need to use is `stat.Age` and `stat.Name` in your iteration.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor='let stat of results;let i = index' [attr.data-index]="i">
   <tr >
     <td style="text-align:left!important;" class="table-row">{{stat.Name}}</td>
     <td class="table-row"> </td>
     <td class="table-row">{{stat.Age}} </td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I`ve corrected the case sensitivity, but still not working...

Comment: it should work... check your code against this: http://plnkr.co/edit/oc5sUlkzZsyxucUjUYmG?p=preview Also I'd use a service to make http requests

Comment: Finally I found what was the problem. I needed to add this.change.markForCheck(); in subscribe and it`s working

Comment: Okay, so change detection was for some reason triggered. Well these things sometimes happen :)